# How to show that at resonance a damped mass-spring system gains no energy?

Tags: energy-conservation, conservation-laws, resonance, vibrations, dissipation

I am having trouble understanding the topic of resonance in vibrations. 
For a simple spring-mass-damper system, I need to calculate the energy from the drive function and compare it with the energy dissipated by the dashpot, showing that they are equal. 
 [image: FBD of my system]

 I have the following equations (that I think are fine) to calculate both the energy injected by the forcing function and the energy dissipated during one period, but it doesn't make sense to me why should these two be equal to one another at resonance. This would mean that F=-c.xdot which ignores the spring in the system.
[image: Energy functions]

Comment: Can we assume the mass is on a frictionless surface?

Comment: Yes, frictionless surface. Only things to worry about are the spring, the dashpot and the forcing function pulling the mass

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the system under consideration is the spring and the mass.

At resonance the system the amplitude of the oscillations is constant and the system is undergoing simple harmonic motion at the frequency of the driver.  So the sum of the kinetic energy of the mass and the elastic potential energy of the spring is constant.
Forces relating to this interchange of energy are internal forces.

This means that you only have to deal with the force exerted by the driver and the force due to friction as the two external forces acting on the spring & mass system.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! In your scenario, is this mass-spring system subject to a driving force? Is it the same system as the one I drew, just without the damper/dashpot or is the forcing function also removed?
Just to make sure I got this clear: with a spring mass system with a force acting on the mass, the energy (potential+kinetic) is constant and therefore the forcing function is the only reason it is so, the spring does not add to remove energy from the system, correct? Thus, when considering generated and dissipated energy for my system, I need only consider the force and the damper.

Comment: The driving force and the frictional force due to the damper are the two external forces to the spring & mass system and those are the two forces which you need to consider in therms of power/energy into the system and power/energy out of the system..